# as3 check if youtube link exists

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to give users of an app the possibilty to post a video from youtube by entering an url in a textfield. To ensure that the link exists, I want to check the url.

I only found examples to check if an external file exists but not how to check a simple www link. How can I check this?

Comment: What is your platform?  AIR or Web (flash player)?  You can listen for the http status event (to see if it's a 404 error or redirect), but on some browsers it doesn't work.  AIR and Chrome would be fine though.   There is an example at the end of the documentation page:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/HTTPStatusEvent.html#includeExamplesSummary

Answer (score 0):

Youtube doesn't really have a 404 page, so you'll always end up loading a page...

I don't know how you'll be loading the page...whether javascript will come into play once the page is loaded and take the argument of the video id...

But if all that goes through.... You'd want to look for this sniped of data in this div to determine whether or not the video exists.

[image]

Comment: Ok I see that's the way to check it. Thanks

Comment: How can I get the source code as a String? Is this possible?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#data

Comment: Great, now I can try. Thanks!!